# Why is check-ert output cut at 70 characters column?

Tags: debugging, column, ert

Sometimes when packaging emacs packages for Debian, I need to debug test failures. Then the debugging output is cut at 70 characters like in this bug report:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=916807#21

excerpt:

```
Test haskell-cabal-compute-checksum-1 backtrace:
  file-name-directory(nil)
  (let ((scriptDir (file-name-directory (or (symbol-file 'haskell-caba
  (closure (t) nil (let ((scriptDir (file-name-directory (or (symbol-f
  ert--run-test-internal(#s(ert--test-execution-info :test #s(ert-test
  ert-run-test(#s(ert-test :name haskell-cabal-compute-checksum-1 :doc
  ert-run-or-rerun-test(#s(ert--stats :selector t :tests [#s(ert-test
  ert-run-tests(t #f(compiled-function (event-type &rest event-args) #
  ert-run-tests-batch(nil)
  ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit()
  command-line-1(("--eval" "(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Why is that and how can I get the full output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is intentional and the fault of `ert-batch-backtrace-right-margin` which is set to 70 by default. Its docstring instructs you:

> Use `nil` for no limit (caution: backtrace lines can be very long).